# Showing a function satisfies a PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations, solution-verification, change-of-variable

I have a question, which should be kind of trivial, but somehow im confused about it. Long story short, I have the following PDE which I achieved from the Feynman-Kac formula:

\begin{align*}
\partial_t F+rx\partial_x F + (\alpha-\lambda v)\partial_vF + \frac{1}{2}vx^2\partial_{xx}F + \frac{1}{2}\sigma_v^2 v\partial_{vv}F + \sigma_v v\rho x\partial_{xv}F-rF = 0
\end{align*}

Then, I know that $F(t,x,v)$ solves this equation, for some $F$, and I also know that it can be represented in the form of a conditional expectation due to Feynman-Kac. The next part is where it gets confusing for me.

Define $G(\tau,x,v) = F(T-\tau,x,v)$, and show that G solves the PDE

\begin{align*}
-\partial_\tau G+rx\partial_x G + (\alpha-\lambda v)\partial_vG + \frac{1}{2}vx^2\partial_{xx}G + \frac{1}{2}\sigma_v^2 v\partial_{vv}G + \sigma_v v\rho x\partial_{xv}G-rG = 0
\end{align*}

So the only thing that changed was the first term. This kinda make sense, since $\partial_x F = \partial_x G$ and $\partial_v F = \partial_v G$ because we did not change the variable. This led me to think that the only thing remaining to show is that

\begin{align*}
\partial_\tau G(\tau,x,v) = -\partial_t F(t,x,v)
\end{align*}

This is where it gets confusing for me. I figured it is something with the chain rule, but i don't know where to begin. How do i compute

\begin{align*}
\partial_\tau G(\tau,x,v) = \partial_\tau F(T-\tau,x,v)
\end{align*}

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\partial_\tau F(T-\tau,x,v)=\partial_{T-\tau}F(T-\tau,x,v)\partial_\tau(T-\tau)=-\partial_tF(t,x,v)$ where $t=T-\tau$.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but this is how i understand it;

We calculate the partial derivative with respect to $\tau$. But because the first entry is a function of $\tau$, namely, $h(\tau) = T-\tau$, the chain rule dictates

$\partial_\tau F(h(\tau,x,v) = \partial_h F(h(\tau),x,v) \partial_\tau h(\tau)$.  

Is this the correct way to think about it?

Comment: That is correct.